# Infopath Form / workflow form not rendering with custom system masterpage

Tags: workflow, infopath, system-master-page

G'Day

I've created a custom master page and I'm applying it as the system master page. Everything works fine except workflows. The following screen shot is showing what happens when I start the OOTB approval workflow.

Here is a link to a screen shot (I can't post one yet sorry)

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=CB773688257049B0!243&authkey=!AE1_GqcAjHM89YM

It just loads to this and stops. I'm not seeing any errors in the browser or the ULS. As far as I can tell I've got all the required delegate controls and placeholders. I suspects it's some sort of JS issue but I can't for the life of me work it out. Any ideas folks? Thanks in advance for the assist.

Here is the link to a copy the file.

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=CB773688257049B0!242&authkey=!ANdrGER8vvGz7vk

Answer (score 0):

Ok - after 2 days on this it turns out a custom control a vendor had written for us was emitting something that was causing the InfoPath controls to error. Control has been removed and everything is working as it should be.